# Angular routerLinkActive not working when we open a route on a new window

Tags: java, angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router

I have a sidenav with 3 list elements. one of the route will be opened in the angular app and rest 2 routes will be opened on a new browser window.

Angular router is working for the route opened with in the app. But angular router is not able to highlight the current route for the external windows.